# Error executing child request during redirect

Tags: configuration, security

I am trying to complete login redirect functionality. I prohibited read/write access for default/anonymous for mysite.org/security-page and added NoAccessUrl `<setting name="NoAccessUrl" value="/login" />`setting. When user visit this page I have an error:
[image: error]
The same error occurs when trying redirect to /404 page.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This issue can be caused by modified setting

`<setting name="RequestErrors.UseServerSideRedirect" value="false" />`

which is `false` by default.

According to notes in config file *If true, Sitecore will use Server.Transfer instead of Response.Redirect*. But Server.Transfer is not good option for regular login page redirect because:

*ASP.NET does not verify that the current user is authorized to view the resource delivered by the Transfer method.*  (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y4k58xk7.aspx).

Comment: Please elaborate on this answer. As it stands, it does not provide sufficient context or explanation.

Comment: yes it was patch config which override this setting. but could you please  explain how it influence to redirect process?